# My png file not showing, my web site in django

Tags: javascript, html, css, png

[image]

This is my website.
I add png file but file is not showing. I build this sıte with django. and my picture src = static/media/python.png
my templates = templates/page/index.html
And my html code.

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class='col'>
        {{article.content|safe}}
        </div>
        <div id="index-2-col">
            <h3>Articles</h3><br>
            <div id="index-polaroid">
                <a href="{% url 'about'%}"><img id="article-image-1"  src="static/media/python.png" alt="Django Lesson 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
                Django Lesson-1
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div id="index-polaroid">
                <a href="{% url 'about'%}"><img id="article-image-1"  src="static/media/python.png" alt="Django Lesson 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
                Django Lesson-1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My css code

```css
#article-image-1{
            
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            display: block;
            
        }

        #index-2-col{
            height: 100%;
            width: 150px;
        }

        #index-polaroid {
            width: 80%;
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 129, 168, 0.445), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            margin-bottom: 15px;
          }
```

What should ı do?

Comment: Don't include `static` in the path for the images.

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same id!!